# Why does 24 MB of CSV data become 230 MB in MongoDB collection?

Tags: mongodb, csv, meteor

My Meteor app takes a CSV file, parses it with Baby Parse (Papa Parse for server) and inserts the data to a MongoDB collection.

Each CSV row is inserted as a document. 24 MB CSV file contains ~900,000 rows; hence, ~900,000 documents in the collection. Each document has 5 fields including the unique id of documents.

When I use `dataSize()` to get collection size, I receive the number 230172976; if I'm not mistaken, this number is in bytes; therefore it is 230 MB.

Why is this gigantic increase happening? How can I fix this?

Comment: Please provide sample rows for a transparent explanation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because the value returns by [`.dataSize()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.dataSize/) include the records [padding](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/glossary/#term-padding). Also note that if your documents don't have the `_id` field it will be added and each `_id` field is `12-byte`. You may want to read [Record Allocation Strategies](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/core/mmapv1/#record-allocation-strategies)

> How can I fix this:

Using the [collMod](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/command/collMod/#dbcmd.collMod) command with the noPadding flag or the [`db.createCollection()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/method/db.createCollection/#db.createCollection) method with the [noPadding](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/command/collMod/#noPadding) option. *But you shouldn't do that because as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/command/collMod/#noPadding)*:

> Only set noPadding to true for collections whose workloads have no update operations that cause documents to grow, such as for collections with workloads that are insert-only.

As  Pete Garafano mentioned in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34455028/why-does-24-mb-of-csv-data-become-230-mb-in-mongodb-collection/34455353#comment56654347_34455353) below, this is applicable for the [MMAPv1 Storage Engine](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/core/mmapv1/) only; which is the default storage engine in MongoDB 3.0 and all previous versions.

MongoDB 3.2 use the [WiredTiger Storage Engine](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/core/wiredtiger/) and you will need to change the default storage engine in order to use that option in your [configuration file](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/configuration-options/) or using the `--storageEngine` option.

Comment: It is important to note that this option only applies to MMAPv1. In MongoDB 3.2, WiredTiger is the default storageEngine.